# Generating a PDF when a document is created in Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm developing an app that creates a PDF based on a web form.

I am currently attempting to use pdfmake to generate the PDFs based on a firestore document create trigger

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
const admin = require('firebase-admin);
admin.initializeApp();
const PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake');
const fs = require('fs');

export const createPDF = functions.firestore
    .document('pdfs/{pdf}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

        var pdfName  = context.params.pdf;
        var printer = new PdfPrinter();

        var docDefinition = {
        // Pdf Definitions
        };

        var options = {
        // Pdf Options
        };

        var pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(docDefinition, options);
        pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('tempDoc.pdf'));
        await pdfDoc.end();


        // Upload to Firebase Storage
        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('myproject.appspot.com');
        bucket.upload('tempDoc.pdf', {
            destination: pdfName + '.pdf',
        });

        return fs.unlinkSync('document.pdf');
    });
```

The trigger is called, however i get the error "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'document.pdf'"

I have tried it with the onCreate function being async and without.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to write to any file location in Cloud Functions outside of /tmp. If your code needs to write a file, it should build paths off of `os.tmpdir()` as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#file_system):

> The only writeable part of the filesystem is the /tmp directory, which
>   you can use to store temporary files in a function instance. This is a
>   local disk mount point known as a "tmpfs" volume in which data written
>   to the volume is stored in memory. Note that it will consume memory
>   resources provisioned for the function.
>
> The rest of the file system is read-only and accessible to the
>   function.

Comment: If i change tempDoc.pdf to path.join(os.tmpdir(), 'tempDoc.pdf'), i still receive the error "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/document.pdf'". I added an import for os and path.

Comment: You're also ignoring all the promises/callbacks returned by async APIs. You need to return a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete.